# Login with new password in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, user-accounts

Few days on-wards my laptop was to slow,I found that 4.6GB of RAM hardware reserved. In the process of fixing, I changed '*msconfig/general/startup-options*'. After the problem fix. While I login into windows it saying "*PIN not available*" and I can't login with password, I forgot it. But have an local non-admin account, I can't turn on WiFi.

After that I decided to take Microsoft customer support, In this process I updated my account password. They said that "*connect LAN cable for 2-3hrs, So that windows can update log files*". But I don't have LAN connection.

**I tried:**

- running `startup-repair` from Advanced restart options. (after choosing "*I forget password*" option, redirecting to local non-admin account login)
- Booting with safe-mode with networking, won't work. (looks like startup-options overriding)
- Turning on WiFi from non-admin account with help of troubleshooter, asking password. (but no forgot password option)
- Simple Reset, asking password. (expected)
- running `bcdedit` command from non-admin account, Access Denied. (expected)
- Connected 3G-modem with USB cable, but not recognizing it as internet device.

Can you please help me. How to login into windows with new password ?

Comment: "connect LAN cable" just means to keep the internet connection while Windows is running, even without login. Are you using a Microsoft Account to login?

Comment: You may have tried to do too many things. You can go to any computer including the one you have, Google for and log into the Microsoft Account web page. This has your email address as Account. Then use the Forgot Password function and reset it. Then you should be able to reset your PIN as well.

Comment: You need an internet connection. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Yes @harrymc,I was using Microsoft account to login, but at login page by default airplane mode is on, there is no option to turn on wifi. Thank you.

Comment: @John, I done reset password, but my windows don't know new updated one. due to networking turned off by msconfig/general/startup-options. Thanks

Comment: Yeah @music2myear, I want to turn on networking. but how? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only works in the case of the problem generated by *msconfig* settings, and you know the "PIN" but windows saying *"Something happened and your pin isn't available"*, Please read the question for more details.

> ### NOTE:  This answer is not responsible for any damage or loss, try at your own risk.

Solution:

- boot with windows installation cd or usb.
- at installation window, press `Shift + f10` or `Shift + fn + f10`
- command prompt opens, go to the drive where windows installed. example `cd c:`
- navigate to `windows\system32`
- rename utilman.exe using `ren utilman.exe utilman1.exe`
- copy cmd.exe as `copy cmd.exe utilman.exe`
- close window and exit, boot to orginal windows
- After boot, at login window click accessibility [icon.](https://www.isumsoft.com/images/windows-10/reset-windows-10-local-user-password-from-login-screen/click-ease-of-access.png)
- In command prompt, run *"msconfig"* command.
- msconfig panel opens, select option *"Normal startup"*, click `apply` and then `OK`
- reboot. enter PIN

After the problem is fixed, don't forget to change everything back to normal again.

- boot again with installation cd or USB.
- open command prompt, go to the drive where windows installed. like above
- navigate to `windows\system32`
- delete utilman.exe using `del utilman.exe`
- rename utilman1.exe as `ren utilman1.exe utilman.exe`
- close window and exit.

some Acknowledgments to
Kirt Kershaw youtube [video](https://youtu.be/pXUpmCf-kd8)